# Question about proving least upper bound

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose sup $A = a$, and sup $B = b$.
I want to prove that $a+b =$ sup $C$ where $C = \{x+y|x \in A, y \in B\}$
Here is what I did:
Let $\epsilon > 0$,
Since sup $A = a$, then $a - \epsilon$ is not an upper bound of $A$. Similarly, for $b - \epsilon$ is not an upper bound for $B$.
Now let $x \geq a - \epsilon, y \geq b - \epsilon$. This imples $x + y + 2\epsilon \geq  a + b$.
And we are done, beacuse in some way $x + y + 2\epsilon$ represent all the upper bounds of $C$.
Therefore, $a+b$ is the suprema of $C$.

Is my proof right?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Just use the definition and see that $x+y$ is the smallest upper bound of $C$ (i.e the supremum).

Answer (score 1):

Your proof has a correct idea, but needs some modification for clarity. I will make some comments below.

> Let $\epsilon > 0$, since sup $A = a$, then $a - \epsilon$ is not an
> upper bound of $A$. Similarly, for $b - \epsilon$ is not an upper
> bound for $B$.
> Now let $x \geq a - \epsilon, y \geq b - \epsilon$. This imples $x + y + 2\epsilon \geq  a + b$.

This is fine so far. For clarity, maybe make some note about how the $x$ and $y$ depend on the $\epsilon$ chosen. The notation $x_\epsilon$ and $y_\epsilon$ is particularly suggestive.

> And we are done, **beacuse** in some way $x + y + 2\epsilon$ represent all the upper bounds of $C$. Therefore, $a+b$ is the suprema of $C$.

It is true that $x_\epsilon + y_\epsilon + 2\epsilon$ is an upperbound of $C$, but in the proof you have not given any reason for us to believe this. In particular how do we know that $a+b$ is an upperbound of $C$?

Moreover, the proof given also does not give us any reason to believe that there can't be a bound lower than $a+b$. The following chain of inequalities, should you prove them, might help

$$\sup C + 2\epsilon \geq x_\epsilon + y_\epsilon + 2\epsilon \geq a+b \geq \sup C$$

---

The proof can be written without a need for $\epsilon$. Use the following outline to prove the statement using only the fact that $\sup C,\sup A,\sup B$ are less than or equal to any upper bound (and the usual rules for manipulating inequalities)

1. Prove that $\sup C\leq a+b$.
2. Prove that $x \leq (\sup C)-y$ for each $x\in A$ and $y\in B$.
3. Hence conclude that $a\leq (\sup C)-y$ for each $y\in B$
4. Rearrange and condlude that $b\leq (\sup C) - a$
5. Hence $a+b\leq \sup C \leq a+b$ and ...